# Using a foreach loop within coloumn data

Tags: php, html, for-loop, foreach

How Can I make it so that it only does foreach on the data and not the html columns?

```
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="title">Donation Amount</div>
        <div class="title">Support</div>
        <div class="title">View Grant</div>

<?php foreach ($results->result() as $grant) : ?>
        <div class="col1"><p>AUD $<?php echo number_format($grant->user_budget);?></p></div>
        <div class="col2"></div>
        <div class="col3"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php endforeach ; ?>
```

Comment: dont put html inside the foreach loop?

Comment: @Waygood But I need to show it with the cols

Comment: @JessMcKenzie - ok what is the exact problem?

Comment: you need to complete div after end `endforeach`

Comment: please add output of this to your question `<pre><?php print_r($results->result()); ?></pre>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   <div class="columns">
        <div class="title">Donation Amount</div>
        <div class="title">Support</div>
        <div class="title">View Grant</div>

<?php foreach ($results->result() as $grant) : ?>
        <div class="col1"><p>AUD $<?php echo number_format($grant->user_budget);?></p></div>
        <div class="col2"></div>
        <div class="col3"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
  <?php endforeach ; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: please print this $results->result() check is there any data or not?

Comment: What was really the question and what was really the answer? I am confused! Glad that Praveen could help you out, but I'm just curious! :-)